# Routing issues after publish asp.net mvc app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I recently developed an asp.net mvc application that want to publish online. I used the Publish option on Visual Studio to do that.

Apparently this is a common task and there are several tutorials about that. However my case has a different detail that I believe is not allowing me to run the app successfully.

So the thing is:

- I have a Wordpress site successfully running at www.somedomain.com
- I want my asp.net application to run at www.somedomain.com/myapp

This is what I have done so far:

1. Uploaded all my app files to httpdocs/myapp folder on the server;
2. Configured a virtual directory on httpdocs/myapp folder on the server;
3. Imported the database from my local computer to the remote server;
4. Changed the connection strings on web.config to point to the database on the remote server;

After this, when I try to access on the browser to www.somedomain.com/myapp I can see that it redirects me to www.somedomain.com/myapp/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fmyapp%2F but shows the 404 error (Page not found) with the layout of my Wordpress site. So it looks like it is running the Wordpress site, instead of the asp.net app on that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you using IIS?

you need to create an application instead of a virtual directory 
otherwise it will not treat the sub folder as an application and will follow parent folder’s web.config and other settings